# Custom window manager and interaction with applications

Tags: x11, window-managers, xcb

I read window managers are responsible for window decorating (title bar, close button, etc.).
So if i can handle, when window is created and modify it somehow (create title bar, close button, etc. for it), how is then application of this window informed, when  close button is clicked? There is always some handler in modern toolkits like QT, where i can react to window closing. It must be some way how to tell may application "hey, your window is closing, wanna do something?". I can't find explanation of this behavior.

Comment: It is all explained in [ICCCM](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/), in particular Section 4. It's somewhat more complicated than most people expect, so be warned.

Comment: more detailed link - http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.2.8.1 In short, you need to handle WM_DELETE_WINDOW message in your client